# How to Call Controller When hit any URL from website in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend, controllers, phtml

I have my custom controller that has my custom code, now I need to run that code when any URL hits from the site.

My Controller URL is like

```
common/index/code run
```

can anyone help me how can I archive this in Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

Comment: Easy way is to use ajax on document load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create `events.xml` at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
      <observer name="my_custom_observer" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\MyClass" shared="false" />
  </event>
</config>
```

2. Now create `MyClass.php` file on following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\MyClass.php

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyClass implements ObserverInterface
{
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
        // THIS EVENT CALL ON EVERY URL
       // insert your custom code here, according to your requirement
   }
}
```